# No puedo enviar contenido de TEXTAREA al correo electrónico

Tags: php, javascript, html5

JS:

```
 function sendForm1(formName){
 var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
 http.open("POST","send-email-macza-2.php",true);
 http.send(JSON.encodeForm(document.forms[formName]));
 http.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
     console.log(http.responseText);
     document.getElementById("envio-exitoso-1").innerHTML="<h1>Datos Enviados Correctamente</h1>";
   }
}
}
JSON.encodeForm = function(form){
  var array = {};
   for (key in form) {
    var item=form[key];
   if(form.hasOwnProperty(key) && item == "[object HTMLInputElement]"){
       array[item.name]=item.value;
   }
 }
  return JSON.stringify(array);
}
```

HTML:

```
       <form action="" method="post" target="_blank" 
        onsubmit='event.preventDefault() ;sendForm1("form-contacto")' 
         name="form-contacto">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">

      <label for="comment">Mensaje</label>
       <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="mensaje"  
       placeholder="Escribir consulta" name="mensaje-contacto-2"></textarea>        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="envio-exitoso-1"></div>
            <input type="submit" value="enviar ">
            </form>
```

Comment: que intentas realizar exactamente?

Comment: Enviar por correo electrónico el formulario de una página web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error lo tienes en la rutina para serializar el formulario.

No estas iterando correctamente los elementos del formulario, anexo te dejo un ejemplo sencillo de como hacerlo.

```js
function sendForm1(formName){
 console.log(JSON.encodeForm(document.forms[formName]));
 var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
 http.open("POST","send-email-macza-2.php",true);
 http.send(JSON.encodeForm(document.forms[formName]));
 http.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
     console.log(http.responseText);
     document.getElementById("envio-exitoso-1").innerHTML="<h1>Datos Enviados Correctamente</h1>";
   }
}
}
JSON.encodeForm = function(form){
 var array = {};
 for (i=0; i<form.elements.length;i++) {
  var item=form.elements[i];
  array[item.name]=item.value;
 }
 return JSON.stringify(array);
}
```

```html
   <form action="" method="post" target="_blank" 
        onsubmit='event.preventDefault() ;sendForm1("form-contacto")' 
         name="form-contacto">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">

      <label for="comment">Mensaje</label>
       <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="mensaje"  
       placeholder="Escribir consulta" name="mensaje-contacto-2"></textarea>        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="envio-exitoso-1"></div>
            <input type="submit" value="enviar ">
            </form>
```